# Disable notifications for a particular account on macOS mail app

Tags: macos, mail.app, catalina, notifications

I have multiple internet accounts linked on macOS for calendar, mail, contacts etc. I wish to disable notifications for a particular account on the mail app. Is it possible to do so?

Answer (score 1):

If you're not worried about the mails for that account, you can set up a rule:

When the mail is addressed to `<this>` account:

- Mark it as read.
- Flag it yellow.

Flagging it would help you read it later. Marking it read should suppress notifications.